# Weird things with machine.config

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, contention, machine.config

I am trying to tune IIS to reduce contention, and following many articles on the .net I am trying to locate this in the file to no result:

```
 <system.web>
     ...
    <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" ... />
     ....
    <processModel maxWorkerThreads="20" maxIoThreads="20" ... />
      ....
 </.system.web>
```

Is it normal that none of the .net framework versions contain a machine.config file that contains the above settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly - if they're not present then the default values will be used.

The default value for [minFreeThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.minfreethreads.aspx) is the same as you're setting , 8, and the default for [minLocalRequestFreeThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.minlocalrequestfreethreads.aspx) is 4.

[maxWorkerThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.maxworkerthreads.aspx) has a default value of 20 as does [maxIoThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.maxiothreads.aspx).

So setting those will make no difference unless someone has set them in the machine.config to lower calues.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. If they're not explicitly stated, the defaults will be used as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268
The one and the only one you need.